# JDBC no inserta datos en la BD

Tags: java, sql

tengo un código en JAVA usando JDBC para conectarme a una BD MySQL. Mi problema es que al hacer un insert de una nueva fila, me devuelve un ID de la fila creada, pero esta no está en la BD, porque hago un SELECT * FROM [tabla] y me sale a null.
Os dejo el código a continuación:

JAVA

```
        ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
        Connection conn = sql.conectarMySQL();
        CallableStatement sentencia = null;
        
        try {
            sentencia = (CallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call newEntry(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
            
            // INICIAMOS LA TRANSACCIÓN
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            
            // Parametros del procedimiento almacenado
            sentencia.setString("id", this.id);
            sentencia.setString("link", this.link);
            sentencia.setString("summary", this.summary);
            sentencia.setString("title", this.title);
            sentencia.setTimestamp("updated", this.updated);
            sentencia.setInt("ids", ids);
            
            // Definimos los tipos de los params de salida del procedimiento almacenado
            sentencia.registerOutParameter("entry_id", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            
            // Ejecutamos el procedimiento
            sentencia.execute();
            System.out.println(sentencia.getInt("entry_id"));
            
            // Se obtiene la salida (parametro nº 7)
            
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("[ENTRY] Error para rollback: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            // Si algo ha fallado, hacemos rollback para deshacer todo y no grabar nada en la BD
            if (conn != null){
                try {
                    conn.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    System.out.println("[ENTRY] Error haciendo rollback: " + e.getMessage());
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // Cerramos las conexiones
            try {
                if (sentencia != null) sentencia.close();
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Si os fijáis, el parámetro nº 7 del procedimiento es uno de salida, que es precisamente el ID de la fila que se ha creado (PK y AUTO INCREMENTAL). Me lo devuelve bien, y saca por pantalla un ID único, pero en la BD no se refleja la fila.

PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO EN LA BD

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `newEntry`(
    IN id VARCHAR(2500), 
    IN link VARCHAR(2500),
    IN summary VARCHAR(400),
    IN title VARCHAR(2000),
    IN updated TIMESTAMP,
    IN ids INT(11),
    OUT entry_id INT(11))
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO tbl_entrys(id, link, summary, title, updated, ids)
    VALUES (id, link, summary, title, updated, ids);

    SET entry_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Por si os lo preguntáis, los datos que le paso son correctos, ninguno se queda a null y todos son del mismo tipo que tengo en la BD. Es más, tengo una clase previa que hace lo mismo, de la misma manera, y este si funciona y crea correctamente la fila en la BD.

Comment: No sé si esto forma de una transacción... ¿quizá se necesite hacer un commit?

Comment: Si, efectivamente, era lo que me faltaba, abría la transacción pero no la cerraba. Gracias.

Comment: [Revisa el tutorial sobre transacciones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html), como bien dice @PabloLozano, cuando usas transacciones, debes confirmar los cambios con `commit()` después del `execute()`, en tu contexto, tendrías que poner: **`conn.commit();`** justo **debajo** de esta línea: `sentencia.execute();`

Comment: Además, pusiste explícitamente `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, como me dijo @PabloLozano, me faltaba hacer el commit de la transacción.

```
ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
        Connection conn = sql.conectarMySQL();
        CallableStatement sentencia = null;
        
        try {
            sentencia = (CallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call newEntry(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
            
            // INICIAMOS LA TRANSACCIÓN
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            
            // Parametros del procedimiento almacenado
            sentencia.setString("id", this.id);
            sentencia.setString("link", this.link);
            sentencia.setString("summary", this.summary);
            sentencia.setString("title", this.title);
            sentencia.setTimestamp("updated", this.updated);
            sentencia.setInt("ids", ids);
            
            // Definimos los tipos de los params de salida del procedimiento almacenado
            sentencia.registerOutParameter("entry_id", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            
            // Ejecutamos el procedimiento
            sentencia.execute();
            System.out.println(sentencia.getInt("entry_id"));
            
            // Hay que hacer el commit para cerrar la transacción que se refleje en la BD             
            conn.commit();

            // Se obtiene la salida (parametro nº 7)
            
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("[ENTRY] Error para rollback: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            // Si algo ha fallado, hacemos rollback para deshacer todo y no grabar nada en la BD
            if (conn != null){
                try {
                    conn.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    System.out.println("[ENTRY] Error haciendo rollback: " + e.getMessage());
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // Cerramos las conexiones
            try {
                if (sentencia != null) sentencia.close();
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```